# How to solve a and b, it may use second derivative

Tags: derivatives

[image]Find the values of the constants a and b such that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}
\frac{(ax+b)^{1/3} -2 }{x} = \frac{5}{12}$$

Thanks a lot for all the answers. However, I know the solution you use, my main question is the same as the picture I published. I think I should use implicit differentiation to find answers for the question because I think b-8 does not have to be equal to 0, which is the main reason I want to ask.

Comment: What have you tried? Or is this just a question dump?

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @夏秋娅 Can you please show your attempts to the problem?

Comment: Actually I finish this question, and I know how to do it before I ask this question. I just cannot understand why b-8 must equal to 0

Comment: @KiênP.S. I have written in my question that it is possible to use the second derivative. This is what I don't understand. Can you explain to me why b-8 must be equal to 0？

Comment: I have indicated my question under the first respondent D1 post when you didn't post the answer. If you don't see it, I hope you can see it clearly next time and then explain the question @ Kiên P.S.

Comment: @Kiên P.S You can delete the post you answered at any time, and I thank you very much for answering this question, and then I will keep the question that I can't understand that b-8 doesn't necessarily equal 0

Comment: @Kiên P.S My solving steps are the same as the first answer because I know how to solve this type of problem, but I can't understand why b-8 equals 0

Comment: I know that the denominator cannot be equal to 0, but this is not the reason b-8 must be equal to 0. I mean that there will be more than one answer to this problem. It can be calculated by using the second derivative, but my solution can not support me to continue to calculate this problem.

Comment: $b-8$ should be equal to $0$, if you want to evaluate the limit. I'm not sure if there's another way to finf a and b when $b$ isn't equal to 8.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, we'll rationalize the numerator (using $a^{3} - b^{3} = (a-b)(a^{2}+ab+b^{2})$):

## $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{ax+b}-2}{x}$$

## $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sqrt[3]{ax+b}-2)(\sqrt[3]{(ax+b)^{2}}+2 \sqrt[3]{(ax+b)}+2^2)}{x ( \sqrt[3]{(ax+b)^{2}}+2 \sqrt[3]{(ax+b)}+2^2)}$$

## $$= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sqrt[3]{ax+b})^{3}-2^{3}}{x (\sqrt[3]{(ax+b)^{2}}+2 \sqrt[3]{(ax+b)}+4)}$$

## $$= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{ax+b-8}{x (\sqrt[3]{(ax+b)^{2}}+2 \sqrt[3]{(ax+b)}+4)}$$

Now, divide both the numerator and denominator by x to calculate the limit:

## $$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{a+\frac{b-8}{x}}{\sqrt[3]{(ax+b)^{2}}+2 \sqrt[3]{(ax+b)}+4}$$

Since the limit exists, $b-8$ has to be equal to $0$, or $b=8$.
Now let's find a:

## $$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{(ax+8)^{2}}+2 \sqrt[3]{(ax+8)}+4} = \frac{5}{12}$$

## $$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{8^{2}}+2 \sqrt[3]{8}+4} = \frac{5}{12}$$

## $$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{8^{2}}+2 \sqrt[3]{8}+4} = \frac{5}{12}$$

## $$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{12} = \frac{5}{12}$$

## $$ a = 5$$

Comment: It would be better to delay your answer until the OP shows some effort.

Comment: Does that mean I should delete my post, and wait until the OP shows her attempts before I post my answer again?

Comment: Yes, as you can always undelete your posts if anything happens.

Comment: what is OP? Actually I finish this question, and I know how to do it. I just cannot understand why b-8 must equal to 0

Comment: OP is Original Poster. People would like to see your attempt to answer the question. Since you showed it, I can undelete my post.